# How to send and received data between Application module to Androidauto module

Tags: android, android-auto

Any idea on how can to send and receive data between Application module to Androidauto. Also how can i put events/listener in Androidauto module if i received data from the application.

Answer (score 1):

With `BroadcastRecevier`.

Use `DefaultLifecycleObserver` on your `Screen` or `Session`

```
class CarHomeScreen(carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private val someBroadcastReceiver = SomeBroadcastReceiver()

    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {}

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        carContext.registerReceiver(someBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)
        super.onCreate(owner)
    }

    override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        carContext.unregisterReceiver(someBroadcastReceiver)
        super.onDestroy(owner)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Local Broadcast Receiver?